# Is there any way to get logged in user azure subscription Id's using @azure/msal-angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, msal.js

I am using @azure/msal-angular to authenticate user. I have done it smoothly as in response i am getting id_Token, access_Token and tenant Id.
Now i need to get logged in user's azure subscriptions.
Is there any way to do it using msal or azure is providing any java script libraries through which i can get user's subscriptions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a GET to `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01` using [their api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list).

You need to provide their token in the Authorization header (i.e. `BEARER <TOKEN>`).